# sql server FOR XML xpath mode: how to generate nested XML id 1 and 2

Tags: sql-server, xml, xpath, for-xml-path, for-xml

I am a xml string as below. I want to use sql server for xml xpath to generate this xml string. I have trouble to get id="IP1" and id="IP2". Would you please help me with it? Thank you very much.

```
    <root>
    <InsuredOrPrincipal id="IP1">
    <GeneralPartyInfo>
    <NameInfo>
    <PersonName>
    <Surname>A </Surname>
    <GivenName>B</GivenName>
    </PersonName>

    </NameInfo>

    </GeneralPartyInfo>

    </InsuredOrPrincipal>


    <InsuredOrPrincipal id="IP2">
    <GeneralPartyInfo>
    <NameInfo>
    <PersonName>
    <Surname>A </Surname>
    <GivenName>B</GivenName>
    </PersonName>

    </NameInfo>

    </GeneralPartyInfo>

    </InsuredOrPrincipal>
    </root>
```

Comment: You need to provide some details. Similar to what you would find here. http://spaghettidba.com/2015/04/24/how-to-post-a-t-sql-question-on-a-public-forum/

Comment: How to generate two InsuredOrPrincipal. The examples only show how to generate one. I don't know how to do two id="IP1" and id="IP2". I need an example to follow.

Comment: What example? Remember we can't see your screen and we have no idea what you are trying to do. I don't understand at all what you are trying to accomplish here.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This should do what you need. You can run the code in SSMS to see it in action.

```
-- create table variable
DECLARE @table TABLE ( id VARCHAR(10), Surname VARCHAR(50), GivenName VARCHAR(50) );

-- insert test data
INSERT INTO @table ( 
    id, Surname, GivenName 
)
VALUES
( 'IP1', 'A1', 'B1' )
, ( 'IP2', 'A2', 'B2' );

-- return xml results from test data as per required schema
SELECT
    id AS 'InsuredAsPrincipal/@id'
    , Surname AS 'InsuredAsPrincipal/GeneralPartyInfo/NameInfo/PersonName/Surname'
    , GivenName AS 'InsuredAsPrincipal/GeneralPartyInfo/NameInfo/PersonName/GivenName'
FROM @table
FOR XML PATH ( '' ), ROOT( 'root' );
```

The resulting XML returned is:

```
<root>
  <InsuredAsPrincipal id="IP1">
    <GeneralPartyInfo>
      <NameInfo>
        <PersonName>
          <Surname>A1</Surname>
          <GivenName>B1</GivenName>
        </PersonName>
      </NameInfo>
    </GeneralPartyInfo>
  </InsuredAsPrincipal>
  <InsuredAsPrincipal id="IP2">
    <GeneralPartyInfo>
      <NameInfo>
        <PersonName>
          <Surname>A2</Surname>
          <GivenName>B2</GivenName>
        </PersonName>
      </NameInfo>
    </GeneralPartyInfo>
  </InsuredAsPrincipal>
</root>
```

I believe this is what you are looking to do. The real "magic" here is in aliasing your column data.

Comment: Thank you very much for your help.

Comment: Is there a way to use [] to solve the probelm.It will make this much easier. I tried it showed me invalid xml path.  root/InsuredAsPrincipal [id='IP1' ]

Comment: To solve *what* problem, Mike? I'm not sure what you're running in to.